# How to launch Nuke with docked panels by default - init.py

Tags: nuke, compositing

I am trying to force docked control panels in Nuke13 by default. When Nuke launches, each node created causes the nodes control panels to float. There is a lock button inside Nuke properties panel to dock them once Nuke is open, but I want this behaviour enforced on start-up, but I cannot find the code to apply this within the init.py.

Thank you

Craig